# Does kernel compiling depends on DTS files

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, compile

I am trying to build a custom Linux kernel.
However I don't understand whether compilation is affected by DTS files under "arch/<...>/boot/dts" or it's only up to the bootloader to pass parameters (in DTB file) to kernel at execution time.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does kernel compiling depends on DTS files

No, the compilation of the Linux kernel is controlled by the **.config** file,  which is the product of running 'make menuconfig'.
The Device Tree is intended as a more specific, runtime configuration to specify the required device drivers and provide salient (i.e. board-related) parameters.

There may be a few header files that are shared between the kernel and Device Trees, but otherwise they can be compiled independently.